# Wordpress Page Template not paginating Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, posts

Wordpress Page Template not using pagination, work display the next and previous links to go back and forth between latest and oldest posts, along with that putting /page/2 just displays the same post too.

Here's the code:-

```
<div id="homeContentLeft">

            <h1>Latest Posts</h1>
            <?php
            rewind_posts();
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args= array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'cat' => 1,
            'paged' => $paged
        );
        query_posts($args);
            ?>

            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="entry">

                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <div id="homeNewsThumbnail">
                        <?php
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                                the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                            } 
                        ?>

                        <div id="homeNewsBoxDate">
                            <large><?php the_time('j') ?></large>
                            <small><?php the_time('M') ?></small>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </a>


                <div id="homeNewsBox">

                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                    <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,320); ?>...

                    <readmore> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">> Read More</a></readmore>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both"></div>

            </div>


            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query();?>
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
            <?php else : ?>
            <h2>Not Found</h2>
            <div class="inner-entry">
                <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

~ Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `rewind_posts()` function is resetting the loop. So your `get_query_var()` call is always pulling from the beginning. Try placing `rewind_posts()` *after* the `$paged = get_query_var(...`

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for that, i actually found out the problem was from reseting the query before the navigation, so it wasn't finding the need to display pages